# The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, telerik-grid

I am getting this error when I try to post Via action link. I have a default map route.

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable  type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Rent_Approval(Kendo.Mvc.UI.DataSourceRequest, Int32)' in .....

Here is my action link

```
@Html.ActionLink("Send For Approval","Rent_Approval", "RentRequisition", new { id = "#=RentID#" }, new { @onclick = "OnIndexCall(this)" })
```

Here is my action method

```
    public ActionResult Rent_Approval([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, int id)
    {
        var record = db.RentRequisitions.FirstOrDefault(p => p.RentID == id);
        try
        {
            if (record != null)
            {
                record.Status = Enum.GetName(typeof(OperationStatuses), 4);
                db.Requisitions.Attach(record);
                db.Entry(record).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }

            var model = new List<RentRequisition> { record };

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax for the link doesn't look correct to me. 
Reference your view model to get the param values in the link's params

try...

```
@Html.ActionLink("Send For Approval","Rent_Approval", "RentRequisition", new { id = Model.RentID}, new { @onclick = "OnIndexCall(this)" })
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. The syntax is actually correct. What you told me to do is bind the parameter at runtime thought that shows me my parameter is null at runtime, my problem is why it looked at is as null while having a value.

Comment: Whats the "@onclick = "OnIndexCall(this)"  ?? Not used that on an action link before? Is that where you bind the param values after the click? Do you need it this way?

Comment: yes to bind it with a Javascript Onclick event to update a master row when updating a detail row (client template).

Comment: I realised I had a problem with my javascript event  "onclick". As I corrected it worked fine. Thanks for reminding me to take a look back at the Javascript code.

Comment: Ah... great... well glad you got it sorted. I was about to say is there an issue with the JQuery ajax post. :)